# Using Dynamic SQL With Objects

Tags: oracle, object, plsql

I have an object and I want to update an object table from with it dynamically. As an example

```
create or replace type typA as object
(
  a number,
  member procedure insert_self
);
/
create or replace type body typA is
  member procedure insert_self is
  begin
    null;
  end;
end;
/
create table typA_table of typA;
/
create or replace type body typA is
  member procedure insert_self is
  sql_stmt varchar2(200);
  begin
    sql_stmt := 'insert into typ_a_table values(self)';
  execute immediate sql_stmt;
  end;
end;
/
declare
  l_typ typA;
begin
  l_typ := typA(123);
  l_typ.insert_self;
end;
```

But this returns an error due to the line which specifies 'self' in the sql_stmt.

```
Error report -
ORA-04063: table "SYSTEM.TYP_A_TABLE" has errors
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.TYPA", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 5
04063. 00000 -  "%s has errors"
*Cause:    Attempt to execute a stored procedure or use a view that has
           errors.  For stored procedures, the problem could be syntax errors
           or references to other, non-existent procedures.  For views,
           the problem could be a reference in the view's defining query to
           a non-existent table.
           Can also be a table which has references to non-existent or
           inaccessible types.
*Action:   Fix the errors and/or create referenced objects as necessary.
```

Is there anyway to get around this error where I'm referencing variables that aren't easily converted to a string?

Comment: always a good idea to run code as a regular user not SYS or SYSTEM

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL in the first place?  I'd expect at a minimum that you'd need to use bind variables and bind the `self` value.  But if that's all you're doing, you wouldn't be using dynamic SQL...

Comment: The ultimate goal is to have a group of objects that are capable of inserting into their own tables, given just the table name.

Comment: Useless use of dynamic SQL ! You might have [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply change your member procedure to something like the below, seems to work for me.

```
create or replace type body typA is
  member procedure insert_self is
  sql_stmt varchar2(200);
  begin
    insert into typ_a_table values(self.a);
  end;
end;
```